# Unity C# respawning prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am currently developing an angry birds style game following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0tl0CwPYIc. I have finished it successfully and works as intended but now i'm trying to implement a respawn feature for the ball to be thrown again and again. i have made the ball as prefab and called it. The ball reappears successfully but it has no rigid body connected or line renderer(spring) therefore the physics arent applied. Any ideas please? Thanks

The prefab settings inspector: https://gyazo.com/7d03b8b99033a34b3bd572451cb3eae2

Comment: Are you sure the prefab you're using has the RigidBody and the spring?

Comment: If you just check what @CNuts says, maybe the answer is push the "apply" button in your prefab; some times you make changes in your prefab but that changes hasn't be done yet because of this button. I know how it sounds but it has happen to me before.

Comment: Cant seem to find the apply button. The rigidbody and spring components are included in the prefab but are always empty unlike the gameobject itself.

https://gyazo.com/0d61d98cb97195e720c4fbb78700c169

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to delete the prefab and recreate it from the GameObject you have on the scene.

But unless you need more than one ball on the scene at a given time, I suggest you a different approach.

Instead of destroying and re-instantiating the prefab, you can simply use `gameObject.SetActive(false)` to deactivate the ball, reset the values in it's components and move it back to its starting position. Then reactivate it and pretend it's a different one.

`Instantiate` and `Destroy` are slow methods and minimizing their use is usually recommended.

Even if you need more than one ball in the scene, there are ways to avoid Instantiation. If you are interested, try looking for Object Pooling in Unity.

Comment: i'll try that method. Do you know if the line renderer will be reinstantiated too along with the ball? because thats what happened so far

Comment: When you deactivate a GameObject it remains on the scene, it's just invisible and Unity won't call Update on it's components. But the object and all of its components are still there. As soon as you reactivate it, Unity will call OnEnable and then restart calling Update every frame on all it's components. So yes, the line renderer will stop drawing while disabled and start doing it again when re-enabled.

Comment: so let me see if i understood you correctly. First on Start it is set to true. I drag and throw it and as soon as its out of the camera view it sets to false and repositioned back and set to true again

Comment: Exactly. Calling `gameObject.SetActive(false)` calls `OnDisable` on every component. Calling `gameObject.SetActive(true)` calls `OnEnable` on every component. So this means you have to put your initialization logic in those two methods. This is how Unity wants you to do it anyway. So you could set the position in `OnDisable` and it will reposition itself to the launch location on its own whenever you deactivate the gameobject and wait there untill you activate it again. `Start` is executed only the first time `OnEnable` is called.

Comment: oh i see. So when  gameObject.SetActive(false) is called, and then gameObject.SetActive(true) automatically it repositions the object to the starting position right?

Comment: I have a method which controls the collision of the ball with an another object and in it i put gameObject.SetActive (false); and then gameObject.SetActive (true); the object's position wasnt reset to the original position though

Comment: update: the position of the ball got reset to the original position but MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'SpringJoint2D' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.

Comment: The position will reset if you put the code to reset it in `OnDisable`. The SpringJoint2d component shouldn't be destroyed if you don't destroy it yourself (either by calling Destroy on it or on it's GameObject). SetActive was meant to be used instead of `Instantiate` and `Destroy`. If you are not calling Destroy on anything, try posting a bit of code relevant to the Exception and the ball component `OnEnable` and `OnDisable`

Comment: I see ok i put  

void OnDisable() {
  transform.position = new Vector3(-10.13f, -2.12f, 0f);
 } 

and position is reset successfully. I have a code which destroys the spring which i need to set to false instead of destroy

Comment: I have the code Destroy(spring) but i cannot remove that because the physics would get screwed. I must keep that line of code and reinstantiate the spring somehow (for reset).

Comment: I never used a SpringJoint2d but I think you have to disable it anyway when the player launches. Something on the line of `springJoint.enabled = false;` (this disable a single component instead of the whole gameObject). I think you just need to move around your initialization logic a bit to make it work. If you want help on that, let's move to the chat or post some code to review.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138125/discussion-between-jack-smith-and-dogiordano).